# How can I stop the SwiftUI app from resetting the form data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Data entered in the textfield disappears and everything resets, after the app is closed and reopened. How can I keep the data from not resetting? Thank you.

```
class Numbers: ObservableObject {
    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    
    @Published var textone: String = " " {willSet {willChange.send()}}
    @Published var texttwo: String = " " {willSet {willChange.send()}}
}

struct FormTest: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var nums = Numbers()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("\(nums.textone)")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Form {
                TextField("", text: $nums.textone)
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 80)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean closed like just going to the background or closed as in force quit?

Comment: Not into the background. Force quit.

Comment: There are a number of solutions to persisting data including UserDefaults, CoreData, writing to files (maybe in JSON format), etc. You might want to look at https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/persisting-data

Comment: By the way, you're using a *very* old (pre 1.0) version of ObservableObject -- you no longer need to include the `PassthroughSubject` or `willSet` code if you're using the the `@Published` property wrappers.

Comment: I did not know that. Cheers.

Comment: Change ObservedObject var nums = Numbers() to   StateObject var nums = Numbers() it is more stable. ObservedObject should only be initialized by a ParentView

Comment: Did you find a strong solution? Perhaps you want to post it as an answer?